# Difference between method signatures of structs

Tags: go

As a programmer coming from other languages like C++, I find it rather strange that go allows to specify methods for structs that allow either a pointer or an instance as a parameter. According to [go by example](https://gobyexample.com/methods) once could use either of them if we didn't want to modify the origin:

> Go automatically handles conversion between values and pointers for method calls. You may want to use a pointer receiver type to avoid copying on method calls or to allow the method to mutate the receiving struct.

Consider the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Foo struct {}

type Bar struct {}

func (this Foo) String() string {
  return "Foo"
}

func (this *Bar) String() string {
  return "Bar"
}

func main() {
  fmt.Println(Foo{}) // "Foo"
  fmt.Println(Bar{}) // "{}"
}
```

Why can't I use both signature versions to modify the *stringify* (I don't know how it is actually called in go) behavior of the structs?

Just to be clear: I don't really care about the stringify, but want to understand how the language behaves.

Comment: You are not calling any methods here, so the quote doesn't really apply. fmt.Println and related functions check if an argument implements fmt.Stringer, but type `Bar` doesn't, only `*Bar` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `&` to the `Bar{}` and make it pointer receiver, like this:

```
fmt.Println(&Bar{}) // "Bar"
```

Here a little adjustment to your code that outputs:

```
Foo
Bar
```

see:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Foo struct{}

func (Foo) String() string {
    return "Foo"
}

type Bar struct{}

func (*Bar) String() string {
    return "Bar"
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Foo{}) // "Foo"
    pb := &Bar{}
    fmt.Println(pb) // "Bar"
}
```

---

Notes:

> Receiver name should be a reflection of its identity; don't use
>   generic names such as "this" or "self"

And you don't need names here for your example.

And nice to read [Golang methods receivers](https://flaviocopes.com/golang-methods-receivers/):

> Value receivers operate on a copy of the original type value. This
>   means that there is a cost involved, especially if the struct is very
>   large, and pointer received are more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Because Bar does not implement `stringer` *Bar does.

If you remove implementation of `stringer` from Foo, you will get "{}".

Similarly, When you write `fmt.Println(Bar{})` it means it will look for something like `func (Bar) String()` and not `func (*Bar) String()`

Additioanlly , story is different when you write `fmt.Println(&Foo{})`, you might think it will print "{}" because there is no `func (*Foo) String()` but it will print "Foo".

For that, you will have to understand Interfaces. These are my experiences so please do your own research too. The `fmt.Print` function calls String() on passed arguments. So actually the String() is not called on your struct but rather than an variable of type stringer.

> interface type can hold a type(which implemented it) or pointer to it,
>   if it was implemented with value receiver. That is why `Foo{}` and
>   `&Foo{}` both work.
>
> interface type can hold a type's pointer (which implemented it)only,
>   if it was implemented with pointer receiver. Why? Because when you
>   implement an interface with pointer receiver, it needs an address
>   which can only be provided with a pointer. That is why only `&Bar{}`
>   works and not `Bar{}`